# Retrieve individual values from datetimeoffset(7) object

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetimeoffset(7) object, I have to convert this object into nvarchar(255) in sql server 2008 r2.
I have source value in format like - '2014-07-01 06:00:00.0000000 +00:00' and desired format is like '07/01/2014 06:00:00 +00:00'.

Below are few ways i tried-

1) DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50) = '2019-10-24 06:00:00.0000000 +00:00' 
SELECT (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), Cast(@a as DATE) ,101)) +' '+ (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),Cast(@a as time))) + ' ' + (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),Cast(@a as offset)))

but in code (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),Cast(@a as offset)) is causing error.

Is there is any way to get offset time zone value from datetimeoffset(7) objet ? or is there is any inbuild method in sql server using that i can get my desired format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datepart` function is your friend. In particular, for the time zone offset, you want `datepart(tz, @a)`. Note that the value returned is the number of minutes, so you still have to change that.

Comment: thanks, I also get one more method in sql server that exactly returns offset value. DATENAME(tz, @a) function gives exact offset value.                                                        DECLARE @a datetimeoffset(7) = '2019-10-24 06:00:00.0000000 +10:00' 
SELECT (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), Cast(@a as DATE) ,101)) +' '+ (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),Cast(@a as time(0)))) + ' ' + (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), DATENAME(tz, @a)))